# Why is $\frac {1}{n^2-1} \le \frac {2}{n^2} $?

Tags: real-analysis

I don't know how to prove that  $\frac {1}{n^2-1} \le \frac {2}{n^2} $.

Can someone help me to understand?

Comment: I presume $n\ge2$. Then that inequality is $\frac1m\le\frac2{m+1}$ for $m=n^2-1\ge3$. Can you prove that?

Comment: NB: "proof" does not equal "prove".

Comment: $\frac{2}{n^2}-\frac{1}{n^2-1}=\frac{n^2-2}{n^2(n^2-1)}$ and look at the sign of the factors. In general, when you have an inequality of a rational function, just pass everything to one side of the inequality and factorize numerator and denominator. Studying the signs of each factor gives the sign of the whole fraction.

Comment: Assuming $n^2 \neq 1$ and $n \neq 0$ you can multiply both sides by $n^2-1$ and $n^2$, then you can simplify to obtain the "proof".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have, for any integer $n\geq 2$,
$$
\frac{n^2-1}{n^2} = 1-\frac{1}{n^2} \geq 1-\frac{1}{4} > \frac{1}{2}\,.
$$
Rearranging gives you the desired inequality:
$$
\frac{2}{n^2} > \frac{1}{n^2-1}\,.
$$

Answer (score 1):

If $2 \leq n$ then 
$$
2 + n^2 < 2n^2 \quad \Rightarrow \quad n^2 < 2(n^2 - 1) \quad \Rightarrow \quad \dfrac{2}{n^2} > \dfrac{1}{n^2-1}
$$